# Recommended column type for 32 character long string (php session id)

Tags: php, mysql

My php.ini is configured to generate 32 character long session ids with following settings:

```
session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length = 512

session.hash_function = 1
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

Thus the string should always be 32 characters long. Is char(32) the most appropriate column type to use if I will be using this column in where statements and having an index on it? Any other best practices I should be aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It would make sense to use `CHAR` for fixed-length strings.  It would also save space in comparison to using `VARCHAR` (again assuming that all values in the column are of same length).

If there is uncertainty in the length of values in the column, there `VARCHAR` would be a preferred choice.

Also see [String Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html).